# Read matrix in matlab from file saved in "stdout" format

Tags: matlab, io

I have a file with the printout of a large matrix, in the same format as it would be if printed to the MATLAB console - i.e. the file starts with

```
dum =

 Columns 1 through 11:

   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000
   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000
   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000
   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000
   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000
   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000
```

and keeps going like this until the entire matrix is printed out. I can figure out a few things about the matrix using e.g. `grep` and `wc`, so it is not entirely unknown, but without these tools and a few manual calculations I have no metadata.

Is there a neater way to read this matrix into MATLAB than trying to parse the file with `fscan`?

Comment: Take a look at dlmread or textscan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around through the file reading utilities in MATLAB I decided I didn't want to use any of them, and instead deviced a small shell script that took the original file and re-wrote it in a regular ASCII format that I could load using `load newfile` in MATLAB.

The full script (explanations of the different parts follow below):

```
for n in `grep -e 'Col' stupiddump.txt | sed 's/ Columns [0-9]* through \([0-9]*\):/\1/'`; do  
    pcregrep --multiline "$n:\\n\\s*\\n([\\d\\.\\s]+)" stupiddump.txt | sed '/\s*Colu.*/d' | sed '/^$/d' > "$n.out"; 
done
paste *.out > betterdump.txt && rm *.out
```

OK, that's A LOT of regexes. I'd be the first to admit that it's not an elegant solution, but it works.

#### [What's really going on here?](https://xkcd.com/208/)

The first `grep` takes out all the rows that say "Columns X through Y:"

```
$ grep -e 'Col' stupiddump.txt
 Columns 1 through 11:
 Columns 12 through 22:
 Columns 23 through 33:
 Columns 34 through 44:
 Columns 45 through 55:
 Columns 56 through 65:
```

The next regex used in `sed`, removes everything but the last number on every line:

```
$ grep -e 'Col' stupiddump.txt | sed 's/ Columns [0-9]* through \([0-9]*\):/\1/'
11
22
33
44
55
65
```

This allows us to search for just one of these sets at a time. So we wrap that nice little script in backticks, and loop through the results:

```
$ for n in `grep -e 'Col' stupiddump.txt | sed 's/ Columns [0-9]* through \([0-9]*\):/\1/'`; do
    echo "The number is $n";
  end
The number is 11
The number is 22
The number is 33
The number is 44
The number is 55
The number is 65
```

The first command inside the loop picks out the relevant part of the data file:

```
$ pcregrep --multiline "$n:\\n\\s*\\n([\\d\\.\\s]+)" stupiddump.txt
 Columns 1 through 11:

   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000
   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000
   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000
etc...
   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000

 Columns 12 through 22:
```

I had to use `pcegrep` to be able to use a multi-line regexp. The `sed`s to which we pipe this, replaces the surrounding text lines with nothing, so that the only thing that remains is the actual matrix content:

```
$ pcregrep --multiline "$n:\\n\\s*\\n([\\d\\.\\s]+)" stupiddump.txt | sed '/\s*Colu.*/d' | sed '/^$/d'
   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000
   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000
   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000
etc...
   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000   1.10000
```

We redirect this output into a file named `"$n.out"`, so that when the loop is done we have a bunch of files named `11.out`, `22.out` etc that contain the corresponding set of columns.

Finally, we use `paste` to horizontally concatenate these files, and remove the temporaries. I was lucky in this case and didn't have to worry about ordering, since numerical and lexical ordering was the same, but if you have a file with column numbers that don't have the same number of digits, you might have to do something smart about that.

```
$ paste *.out > betterdump.txt && rm *.out
```

Now, `betterdump.txt` is in approximately the same format as it would have been if I'd have typed `save -ascii A` to save the matrix in the first place, and thus I can read it easily with `load`.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps you can take to import this kind of data into matlab without digging too much into the available functions:

1. Rightclick the file from inside matlab
2. Click import data
3. Select matrix
4. Set range A3:K6 (Or where the file ends)
5. Click import, or click generate code

From this you will get code like this:

```
filename = 'U:\MATLAB\dum.txt';
delimiter = ' ';
startRow = 3;
formatSpec = '%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%[^\n\r]';
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
textscan(fileID, '%[^\n\r]', startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', true, 'ReturnOnError', false);
fclose(fileID);
dum = [dataArray{1:end-1}];
clearvars filename delimiter startRow formatSpec fileID dataArray ans;
```

It should not be hard to use this code or adapt it to make it more convenient.

Comment: Will this work even though the matrix has more columns than what fits in one "set", i.e. there's another line further down with `Columns 12 through 22:` etc?

Comment: @TomasLycken In that case you would probably want to import it as a cell array first (Rather than a matrix) and do some post processing afterwards.